# .NET Deployment Options with Patch management / Automatic updates

Tags: .net, deployment, installation, patch

What are the options available to deploy a .NET desktop application built using WPF other than ClickOnce?

Top priorities are

- should work over the wire (internet or intranet)
- updates management; options to check for software updates and automatic updates.
- patch management; download and update only those files which has changed.

Comment: Anything in particular about ClickOnce that you don't like?

Comment: Our support team is having hard time finding to which folder app was installed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### [Dot Net Auto Update](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetautoupdate)

I've implemented a library to do this called [DotNetAutoUpdate](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetautoupdate) (original name eh?). It aims to be:

- Simple to use
- Simple to setup
- Secure - see [Auto update: Is this secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419800/auto-update-is-this-secure)

It doesn't handle differential patches at the moment but perhaps in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776.aspx) deployment?

Answer (score 0):

This tool might help: http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.Update/

Comment: Page updated 2008, not sure if this is a good or a bad sign though :-)

Comment: The latest release was made 2009-01-02.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) which claims "It's like ClickOnce but Works™"