# Automatic update solutions for a Win32 application?

Tags: windows, winapi, auto-update

We've got a desktop product, made up of a Win32 service, a notification icon application and associated DLL files.

I've been tasked to look at making it auto-update. We could write our own updater, but before we do that, I'd like to see what else is out there. Are there any commercial systems (similar to Windows Update, I guess) that we could use? I'm sure that InstallShield used to offer something like this, but I can't find it now, and it's possible that my memory's failing me.

It's a Win32 application (and a service), so ClickOnce is out (or is it?).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Google's Omaha project](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/).
I once looked into using it.  But I eventually realized it would be easier to re-invent the wheel than to learn everything that goes into making Omaha work.  Unfortunately I have yet to find a generic solution.  Most project's I've looked into tend to build their own updater.

Which is bad, because everyone tends to make the same mistakes over and over again.  Doing secure updates isn't trivial.  Read this:
[Auto update: Is this secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419800/auto-update-is-this-secure)

I also find it rather annoying how every auto updater thinks it needs to be running 24/7 in my system notification area.

I would venture to say that one of the main advantages of of the app store model is that developers don't have to worry about building an update system.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend GUP: https://wingup.org/

It's the automatic updater developed by Notepad++ author and it's completely opensource.

Comment: How can we update the application as patches rather than downloading the whole application?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310530/Target-Eye-Revealed-part-Target-Eyes-Unique-Auto). Source code (c++) included.